# How do you forward declare the `bool` type in a C header file?

Tags: c

Consider a header file, **myheader.h** with the following function header:

```
bool isValid(char c);
```

And whose implementation file, **myimplementation.c**, contains:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isValid(char c) {
  return c == 'Y' || c == 'N';
}
```

If one would like to avoid `include`ing *stdbool.h* in the header file, how does one properly "forward declare" the `bool` datatype in the header file?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `#include <stdbool.h>` in the header file? Its contents won't be much.

Comment: You include what you need in _your_ header. Others who need your header will get what you provide. It may be the macro `bool` (for `_Bool`) or - you may decide to use the keyword `_Bool` in your code to leave all that behind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want "bool", you should include "stdbool.h":

> https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean
>
> **Boolean type support library**
>
> The C programming language, as of C99, supports Boolean arithmetic
> with the built-in type _Bool (see _Bool). When the header <stdbool.h>
> is included, the Boolean type is also accessible as bool.
>
> **Macros**
>
> ```
> Macro name                        Expands to
> ----------                      ----------
> bool                          _Bool
> true                          integer constant 1
> false                         integer constant 0
> __bool_true_false_are_defined integer constant 1
> ```

If including <stdbool.h> in every source file that uses "bool" really annoys you, Ted Lyngmo made a good suggestion: simply define your own header, and include stdbool.h there.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what I suggested :-) I suggest using the keyword `_Bool` - you rarely go wrong with keywords.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo: Fair enough: `_Bool` is standard C99; no headers required.  I thought you suggested a header as a way for the OP to use "bool" without having to include <stdbool.h>.  Frankly, I'm not sure why anybody would have problems with either "_Bool" or "<stdbool.h>".  But if the OP doesn't like either, a custom application header would be a reasonable alternative.  The header could `#include <stdbool.h>`, or it could `#define bool _Bool`.

Answer (score 2):

First, there is no need to declare `bool`; you can simply declare the function as `_Bool isValid(char c);`.

Second, C 2018 7.18 2 says `<stdbool.h>` defines `bool` to be a macro that is replaced by `_Bool`. You can simply do this yourself with `#define bool _Bool`. 7.18 4 says that a program may undefine and redefine `bool`. To be pedantic and extra safe in conforming to that, you could use:

```
#undef bool
#define bool _Bool
```